# Liferay not starting in tomcat. "Startup failed due to previous errors"

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I have a Liferay 6.0.6 instance running in Tomcat 6.0.29. It was working fine till yesterday for last one year. But yesterday the server stopped responding and after I tried to restart the server, The liferay service couldn't start.

Following is the startup log -

```
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:6060
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:158)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    ... 12 more
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:6060
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:548)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 766 ms
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
May 21, 2014 2:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Loading jar:file:/apps/zensar/zenloungeplus/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/apps/zensar/zenloungeplus/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/apps/zensar/zenloungeplus/liferay-portal-6.0.6/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
May 21, 2014 2:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 21, 2014 2:49:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory more-activities-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory PollingWidget-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory bottom-bar-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory blogsrecommended-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Spark-Wall-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory social-networking-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory friends-in-village-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory userToolBox-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory accolades-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spark-portal-theme
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory chat-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory nav-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spark-jugnu-theme
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory zensarapplications-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory codeofethics-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory global-community-links-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory friend-mutual-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Zenpoints-rank-community-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spark-hook
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory solr-web
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory importusercsvfile-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory zenpoints-ranking-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory user-recommendations-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory thought-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory birthday-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory messageboards-migration-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Page_Creator-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory community-mutual-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Video-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Support-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory friend-recommends-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory banner-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory birthday
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory zensapience
May 21, 2014 2:49:16 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory wsrp-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory CommunityPortrait-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory OurValues-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory web-form-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory friend-community-mutual-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory codeofethicslog-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spark-friends-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory profile-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory spark-villages-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory community-activities-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory PollResult-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory AdvertSpace-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory 1-3-1-columns-layouttpl
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory tunnel-web
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory zenplusadds-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory Excellence_Awards-portlet
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:6060
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:565)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:158)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
        ... 12 more
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start:
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:6060
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1094)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 62288 ms
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[6005]:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:353)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:336)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:614)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
May 21, 2014 2:49:18 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6060
May 21, 2014 2:49:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 21, 2014 2:49:19 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/wsrp-portlet] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder] (value [org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils$ThreadLocalDocumentBuilder@211c0042]) and a value of type [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl] (value [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl@3554fe09]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
May 21, 2014 2:49:19 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:176)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:648)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:692)
May 21, 2014 2:49:19 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6060
May 21, 2014 2:49:19 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started
```

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is explicit:

```
Address already in use <null>:6060
```

Either you are trying to start it a second time with a previous instance running or something else is listening on port 6060.

Comment: Hi Jim,
I killed all processes for port 6060 and restarted the server. Now I don't get "Address already in use error". But still Liferay isn't starting.

Comment: The following errors still come while starting the server - 
'SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 21, 2014 3:29:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
May 21, 2014 3:29:14 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Dispatch-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@76e222eb] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
'

Comment: Replace the stack trace in your post with the complete new stack trace.  We have to see what the "previous errors" are.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help Jim. I figured out the problem and fixed it.
The problem was that the DB connection thread was in a deadlock (mentioned in the logs of my previous comment) and fixed it by restarting the DB service on our DB server.